# Как обновлять аяксом ссылки?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Проблема возникает в том, что нужно при загрузке страницы вывести список ссылок, после обновлять их каждые(ну допустим 2 минуты) при большом времени обновления они сразу при перезагрузке не отображаются, а при маленьком...настолько часто происходит обновление, что переход по ним невозможен ... как доработать это...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){
$.ajax({
 url: "pages/blocks/message/me.php",
 success: function(html){
 $('#dau').html(html);
}
});
}
setInterval('show()', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Очевидно, что интервал начинает отсчитываться с момента вызова функции `setInteval`. Вызовете свой обработчик `show` сразу после загрузки, а по его окончанию - запустите таймер.

Comment: спасибо ...window.onload = show;